# Application compiled by Flex Builder 3 does not trace

Tags: apache-flex, flash, trace, flashlog

I've built a simple application in Flex Builder 3 with some trace() calls. It's an "ActionScript Project", no MXML or AIR involved. I don't run the app from within Eclipse, I just open the generated html file with Firefox.

I'm using the Flash Player 10 Debug version. I've correctly set mm.cnf to log trace output, following the official instructions. A flashlog.txt file is generate in the appropriate location.

Despite all that, trace output is not shown in the log file. What am I doing wrong?

(I suspect it's a compiler option, but I can find no such option in the project options in FlexBuilder)

(If I do run the app from Eclipse, by pressing F11, I can see trace output but only inside Eclipse, not in the log file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow it solved itself

Comment: YAY for self correcting problems. Wish all bugs had the same courtesy.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the -debug compiler argument to true.

Is there anything in the flashlog.txt, or is it completely empty?

Comment: It is empty. Also when I try to add -debug it says "Option -debug cannot be used when compiling with Flex Builder" :S

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use [De MonsterDebugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/) instead?

De MonsterDebugger is an open source debugger for Adobe Flash, Flex and AIR. De MonsterDebugger is made in Flex and AIR by design studio De Monsters.

If that doesn't work google "fxspy" or "Alcon debugger".  Those are two other good debugging options.